# Suffrage Badge awarded on incorrect site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, stackexchange-2.0

I used up my 30 votes for the day on the [Game Dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange, and then when I visited Stack Overflow (right afterwards) I was awarded the Suffrage Badge there (and not on GameDev)

Edit: Just Received the Badge on GameDev, still have it on SO though. Wondering if it affects the other sites.

Comment: Yep, gives me the badge on other SE sites that I visit also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existing users were checked for the Suffrage criteria when the badge was introduced.  You got the badge for SO on a previous day.